# How to mock using external call in Akka Actor using ScalaTest

Tags: scala, akka, mockito, scalatest, akka-testkit

I am new to entire ecosystem including `Scala`, `Akka` and `ScalaTest`

I am working on a problem where my `Actor` gives call to external system.

```
case object LogProcessRequest

class LProcessor extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  def receive = {
    case LogProcessRequest =>
      log.debug("starting log processing")
      LogReaderDisruptor main(Array())
  }
}
```

The `LogReaderDisruptor main(Array())` is a `Java` class that does many other things.

The test I have currently looks like

```
class LProcessorSpec extends UnitTestSpec("testSystem") {

  "A mocked log processor" should {
    "be called" in  {
      val logProcessorActor = system.actorOf(Props[LProcessor])
      logProcessorActor ! LogProcessRequest
    }
  }
}
```

where `UnitTestSpec` looks like (and inspired from [here](http://www.superloopy.io/articles/2013/scalatest-with-akka.html))

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestKit}
import org.scalatest.matchers.MustMatchers
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, WordSpecLike}

abstract class UnitTestSpec(name: String)
  extends TestKit(ActorSystem(name))
  with WordSpecLike
  with MustMatchers
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with ImplicitSender {

  override def afterAll() {
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

**Question**

- How can I mock the call to `LogReaderDisruptor main(Array())` and verify that it was called?

I am coming from `Java`, `JUnit`, `Mockito` land and something that I would have done here would be

```
doNothing().when(logReaderDisruptor).main(Matchers.<String>anyVararg())
verify(logReaderDisruptor, times(1)).main(Matchers.<String>anyVararg())
```

I am not sure how to translate that with ScalaTest here.

Also, This code may not be idiomatic, since I am very new and learning

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. The kind of OO way is to wrap logDisrupter as an object and pass it in. I would set up a companion object to instantiate the actor. Something like below. Then you can pass alternate implementation. You can also achieve a similar approach by using traits and mixing in an alternative logDisrupter only as needed.

```
object LProcessor {
   def props(logDisrupter : LogDisrupter) = Props(new LProcessor(logDisrupter))
}

class LProcessor(logDisrupter : LogDisrupter) extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  def receive = {
    case LogProcessRequest =>
      log.debug("starting log processing")
      logDisrupter.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Then instatiate as

```
val logProcessorActor = system.actorOf(LProcessor.props(logDisrupter))
```

Comment: This sounds like an excellent advice. This is however challenging in my scenario since `LogDisrupter.main` is a `static` method in `Java` class that is a dependent library

Comment: Can't you wrap it in an object. e.g. class LogDisrupterWrapper { def doSomething = LogDisrupter.main } and pass around the wrapper.